# I want to know if i have the right to push someone if they slapped me in self defense

Tags: germany, self-defense

I have a question, about 3 or 4 months ago, i was just outside chilling with some of my friends and then some girl came and slapped me, all i did was push her back in self defense. I just want to know if that is legal or not. I live in Germany, thank you.

Comment: Does "in self defense" belong to "push" or to "slapped"?  On reflection it seems like it must be "pushed," but the word order here made me think at first that you had been "slapped in self defense."  Can you clarify?

Comment: Basically she slapped me and so after a second i gently pushed her away.

Comment: Did something happen when you pushed her? Did she fall, did she get injured, was she in any danger of falling off a cliff or something? Did she topple something when she stumbled back? Just "pushing her" is probably a crime on paper, but I cannot see any cop or DA in their right mind coming after someone for "pushing" someone, if it did not actually create a danger(ous situation).

Answer (score 2):

If you pushed her back **after** she slapped you **and** it is not clear that a second slapping would occur (**or** she slapped you, because you pushed her)

- then it is **not** self-defence

  - you (**or** she) did not **prevent a present** unlawful attack

If it is clear that you are **going to be** slapped

- then pushing her away, in a reasonable manor, is self-defence

  - you **prevented a present** unlawful attack

What is considered **reasonable** will later be determined by a judge.

---

> [§ 32 - Self-defence StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p0186)
> (2) ‘Self-defence’ means any defensive action which is necessary **to avert a present** unlawful attack on oneself or another.

---

**Sources**:

- [§ 32 - Self-defence StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p0186)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147819/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-johnson-i-want-to-know-if-i-have-the-right-to-push); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.